# I can´t find the path of Slider1, i want to set a value for it.

Tags: path, slider, applescript

my problem is that i can´t manage to find the correct path of a slider that i want to set a value to.

This is the code that i have at the moment, there is also the UIElemtInspector path, any help is very much appreciated. :)

UIElemtInspector path:

```
<AXApplication: “OSCulator”>
<AXWindow: “Preferences”>
<AXTabGroup>
<AXGroup>
<AXSlider>

Attributes:
AXRole:  “AXSlider”
AXRoleDescription:  “slider”
AXHelp:  “(null)”
AXEnabled:  “1”
AXFocused (W):  “0”
AXParent:  “<AXGroup>”
AXWindow:  “<AXWindow: “Preferences”>”
AXTopLevelUIElement:  “<AXWindow: “Preferences”>”
AXPosition:  “x=263 y=513”
AXSize:  “w=214 h=21”
AXValue (W):  “20.35702720207254”
AXMinValue:  “0”
AXMaxValue:  “100”
AXChildren:  “<array of size 1>”
AXAllowedValues:  “(null)”
AXOrientation:  “AXHorizontalOrientation”
AXIdentifier:  “_NS:405”

Actions:
AXIncrement - increment
AXDecrement - decrement
```

---

Code:

```
  if application "OSCulator" is running then
  tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "OSCulator"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "OSCulator"
                tell menu "OSCulator"
                    click menu item "Preferences..."
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
tell application "OSCulator" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "OSCulator" to tell window "Preferences" to tell tab group 1
    click radio button "Outputs"

end tell

end if
```

Answer (score 1):

As the UIElementInspector says, the slider is in a group. You can show every group like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "OSCulator"
    tell window "Preferences" to tell tab group 1
        click radio button "Outputs"
        get every group
    end tell
end tell
```

result:

```
group "Kyma" of tab group 1 of window "Preferences"...
group "HID" of tab group 1 of window "Preferences"...
group "Mouse" of tab group 1 of window "Preferences"...
```

now you can look for the slider:

```
get every UI element of group "Mouse"
```

and then finally set the slider:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "OSCulator"
    tell window "Preferences" to tell tab group 1
        click radio button "Outputs"
        set value of slider 1 of group "Mouse" to 50
    end tell
end tell
```